# How can I get jqzoom position absolute?

Tags: jqzoom

I'm trying to make JQzoom's zoompad absolute positioning on my page. I did try to change the CSS but it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, I have found another image-zoom plugin to solved the position need. The plugin call Easyzoom if you like to know. link: http://cssglobe.com/jquery-plugin-easy-image-zoom/